# Filter loses access to internal objects' methods when passed through a generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, lambda, filter, java-8

I have a paralell stream in a method, and it works just fine when I run at it this way.:

Meeting is an interface whose implementations have a private int id member field and one getter method getId();

```
public class MyClass {
   private List<Meeting> myMeetings = new ArrayList<>();

   public PastMeeting getPastMeeting (int id){
            Meeting meetingWithId;
            meetingWithId = myMeetings.parallelStream()
                    .filter(meeting -> meeting.getId() == id )
                    .findFirst()
                    .get();
            return meetingWithId;
        }
}
```

However, I'm going to have to perform this action from several other methods within myClass, so I needed to make that action its own method and I have added the below method to myClass, as I may have different implementations of Meeting and thus different types of the List as well, so I made the parameter a generic. However, when I run it this way, the filter is unable to get access to the Meeting's getId() method, saying it "cannot resolve m.getId();"

```
private <T, R> T returnMeeting(T meeting, List<R> meetingList, int id) {        
        meeting = meetingList.parallelStream()
                .filter(m -> m.getId() == id )
                .findFirst()
                .get();
        return meeting;
}
```

I'm not sure why, as the code is exactly the same. Has running through generic parameter fields caused a disruption in what the lambda can assume? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you dont add type bounds to the generic parameters you only have the methods on `Object` available.

You have two options:

Add a type bound that enforces a specific type/interface that has the methods you want to use.

```
interface IdProvider {
   int getId();
}

private <T extends IdProvider> T returnMeeting(List<T> meetingList, int id)    {        
    return meetingList.parallelStream()
            .filter(m -> m.getId() == id )
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

Or you add another parameter to the method that defines how the id is resolved

```
private <T> T returnMeeting(List<T> meetingList, int id, Function<T,Integer> idGetter) {        
    return meetingList.parallelStream()
            .filter(m -> idGetter.apply(m).equals(id) )
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't need two parameter variables `T` and `R` - they both always be the same. So you can remove `T meeting` arguement.

Second, make explicit to the compiler that `R` type is something that implements the `Meeting` interface, so has `getId()` method.

```
List<R extends Meeting> meetingList
```

The whole code:

```
private <R extends Meeting> R returnMeeting(List<R> meetingList, int id) {
        return meetingList.parallelStream()
                .filter(m -> m.getId() == id )
                .findFirst()
                .get();
}
```

Also note, that `.get()` can cause `NullPointerException` here if meeting is not found in the list, so better use `.orElse(null)` or just return the `Optional` itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, returning an Optional is not an option in this case. If I use the .orElse(null), I then can no longer call get() to return a Meeting. Would there be an easy way to return a null meeting?

Comment: @NateH06 What do you think `orElse()` does?

Comment: @NateH06 `orElse(null)` exactly does that! Returns found `Meeting` or `null` if nothing found. You don't need `get()` after `orElse()`. `orElse(null)` is like `if (!optional.isEmtpy()) { return optional.get(); } else { return null; }`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks! I had thought orElse() returned an Optional on its own. Before, `get()` was throwing a `NoSuchElementException`, but now `.orElse(null)` is throwing a `NullPointerException` when I call the method, such as this (assume  myBadInt is not contained in the meetingList) : 
`Meeting myMeeting = returnMeeting(meetingList, myBadInt);

Comment: `Meeting myMeeting = returnMeeting(meetingList, myBadInt)`

(had to add another comment to put last line in code format, got timed out) @shmosel

Comment: No, your `returnMeeting` just returns `null` if you use `.orElse(null)`. There is something else futher in your code, which uses that returned value and throws `NullPointerException`. Watch the stracktrace where this `NPE` thrown. And actually this is exactly a reason why returning `Optional` is a better idea and why the `Optional` class was introduced into Java language. This forces the code, which will use returned value to explicitly check if it present or not.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I had code elsewhere calling it like this:
`if (returnMeeting(futureMeetingList, id).equals(null) ) {...}`
and the fix was 
`if (returnMeeting(futureMeetingList, id) == null ) {...}`

Thanks for your very dedicated help.

Answer (score 3):

Your generic parameters give no indication they're of type `Meeting`. Also, the `meeting` parameter is unnecessary. Try this instead:

```
private <T extends Meeting> T returnMeeting(List<T> meetingList, int id) {        
    return meetingList.parallelStream()
            .filter(m -> m.getId() == id )
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
}
```